# Share Extension

Tags: ios, core-data, share

i want access the CoreData of main application to share extension.
I created App Group in Apple developer and added to app.
While adding App group for share extension getting errors.
Please do check screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe a provisioning profil problem, you can try remove the old ones, then turn off/on the App Group feature. If it doesn't work, check if your widget has this App Group id on Apple Developer portail

Comment: i am using automatic singing and already created new provisioning profile, does't work.

Comment: You need to enable it in the App Id also. Edit the APP Id in developer account and enable the option

Comment: @Shruti its already enable thats why it added in the application.
if its not added then main application also got error, please refer to screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled the "App Groups" service for the main app bundle identifier only. You need to enable it for the share extension bundle identifier also. Please go to developer.apple.com and enable it.

[image: App Groups]

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but i Already did activated and added in both app and extension.
but Xcode not picking up the App Groups for extension.

Comment: @Optimus: Did you add that in the developer.apple ? If yes please download the provisioning profiles and add them, after that do a clean and re-build